# Overcoming the critical angle of total internal reflection?

Tags: optics, reflection, diffraction

Incident light on an interface between an optically denser medium (refractive index $n_1$) and a less dense medium ($n_2$) will undergo total internal reflection (TIR) if the angle of incidence (AOI) is $\theta > \theta_\text{c} \arcsin \left( \frac{n_2}{n_1}\right)$.

I would like to overcome this (at least theoretically). Using standard (AR) coatings will not change $\theta_\text{c}$. Is this possible with diffraction gratings? How?

Or are there other strategies one could think of?

Frustrated total internal reflection (FTIR) is not an option since I would like the light beam to be transmitted in medium 2.

Comment: In FTIR the light beam is (partially) transmitted in medium 2.

Comment: @sammygerbil yeah, of course, but I meant, the light should "end up" in (the infinitely extended) medium 2 rather than a medium 3

Comment: Oh yes sorry I see what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

Total internal reflections occurs because of there are fewer optical modes outside the waveguide than inside. So yes, it’s possible to apply a diffraction grating to the surface of a wave guide to out-couple trapped modes (obviously this works in reverse too). The grating matches internal modes to external propagating modes. This is explained nicely by [ROSENBLATT et al.: RESONANT GRATING WAVEGUIDE STRUCTURES](https://doi.org/10.1109/3.641320)

[image: Resonant grating waveguide structure]

An incident plane-wave is diffracted into the first order mode according to,

$$n_1 k \sin(\theta) + mK = n_3 k \cos(\phi)$$

Where $k$ is the wave vector and $K$ is the grating wave vector.

Another approach, and this is crucial to the operation of high efficiency solar cells and LEDs, is surface roughness. Multiple scattering events redirects trapped modes into escaping modes. The diagram below is taken form the seminal paper on the topic [Statistical ray optics (1982)](https://doi.org/10.1364/JOSA.72.000899)

[image: Yablonovitch brightness]

Comment: The diagram is not self explanatory, and the linked article is hidden behind a paywall. Please could you include the caption and/or enough text to explain what the diagram means.

Comment: So basically, I just need a grating with the right k vector (which is added to the beam's k vector) to decrease the refraction angle to $< \frac{\pi}{2}$? If I want the beam to remain coherent and with a not too complex phase, scattering doesn't sound like a good idea although it's obvious that it helps if you don't care about that. Thanks for mentioning it anyway, as you said it's important for many applications.